# How is this question still here?

Tags: discussion

The question: [Did lightning strike the St. Peter basilica the night the Pope resigned?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14974/how-can-the-news-that-lightning-struck-the-st-peter-basilica-the-night-the-pope) says that the OP believes the claim, and just wants to know how to prove a claim of a that kind. those questions should belong to to the Meta, if at all.

> So, what is the best way to find out more about this event? I'm not doubting it, I'm just curious how such an event can be verified or refuted.

Why wasn't this question deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question with a question:

- Did you flag it for deletion?
- Did you consider editing it? (i.e. to "Did lightning strike the St. Peter basilica the night the Pope resigned?", and indicate in the body that a more definitive answer than journalist's report it, unreferenced, is desired.)

Comment: I didn't flag it for deletion, but I did vote to close it. I didn't edit it, a. Because I haven't seen the claim and it doesn't appear in the question. b. If the question was edited to "Is this picture was taken on the day of the resignation in the Vatican?", then it becomes one of those unfalsifiable question.

Comment: I agree we will never prove the answer to 100% guarantee, but the photographer's personal statement seems to have been enough to satisfy the OP in this case. (As it should - it was far from an extraordinary claim, and of little import. We should be willing to accept rather mundane evidence as sufficient.)

Comment: I just tried to edit this question to make it more "questiony" and less meta. Please take a look to see that I didn't over edited.

Comment: Looks like a big improvement to me.

Comment: I must say it's a pretty huge edit... And completely opposites the tone of the question. From religious bias to anti-religious bias.

Comment: @Wertliq: Are we all talking about the same edit? http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/revisions/14974/2